# What’s this slim rectangular box on my utility pole?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, wireless, telecommunications

It’s the silver box on the utility pole here:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with that box?

Comment: Just want to know what it is..someone told me before it’s a small cell for 5G but I don’t see any antennas

Comment: My assumption is it is a cable junction box similar to the black on on the cable line...